gcc seems cannot locate C header file even in path to search
I'm trying to compile a driver from https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8822bu on Linux Mint (6.8.0-38-generic #38-Ubuntu). I've already fixed couple of issues (e.g. did sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib from "fatal error: bits/libc-header-start.h: No such file or directory" while compiling HTK), now I see running make:
$ make
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/6.8.0-38-generic/build M=/path/Downloads/rtl8822bu-master modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.8.0-38-generic'
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-13 (Ubuntu 13.2.0-23ubuntu4) 13.2.0
  You are using:           gcc-13 (Ubuntu 13.2.0-23ubuntu4) 13.2.0
  CC [M]  /path/Downloads/rtl8822bu-master/core/rtw_br_ext.o
/path/Downloads/rtl8822bu-master/core/rtw_br_ext.c:26:18: fatal error: netipx/ipx.h: No such file or directory
   26 |         #include <netipx/ipx.h>//<net/ipx.h> /usr/include/netipx/ipx.h"
      |                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:243: /path/Downloads/rtl8822bu-master/core/rtw_br_ext.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.8.0-38-generic/Makefile:1926: /path/Downloads/rtl8822bu-master] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:240: __sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.8.0-38-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:1319: modules] Error 2

But
$ locate netipx/ipx.h
/usr/include/netipx/ipx.h

include was originally <net/ipx.h>, I've changed it now to <netipx/ipx.h> and get error above. If it is "/usr/include/netipx/ipx.h" it passes but more errors come, e.g.
/usr/include/netipx/ipx.h:22:10: fatal error: stdint.h: No such file or directory 22 | #include <stdint.h>
which is in even two places in search paths (see below)
$ locate stdint.h
/usr/include/stdint.h
/usr/include/c++/13/tr1/stdint.h
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/include/stdint.h

Web search found e.g. sys/types.h: No such file or directory (I've got libc6-dev newest already)
From answer in Where does gcc look for C and C++ header files?
`gcc -print-prog-name=cpp` -v

Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=cpp
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:amdgcn-amdhsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 13.2.0-23ubuntu4' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-13/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,m2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-13 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/libexec --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-libstdcxx-backtrace --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --enable-libphobos-checking=release --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --enable-cet --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none=/build/gcc-13-uJ7kn6/gcc-13-13.2.0/debian/tmp-nvptx/usr,amdgcn-amdhsa=/build/gcc-13-uJ7kn6/gcc-13-13.2.0/debian/tmp-gcn/usr --enable-offload-defaulted --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 13.2.0 (Ubuntu 13.2.0-23ubuntu4) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-E' '-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/cc1 -E -quiet -v -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu - -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Wformat-security -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -dumpbase -
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/include-fixed/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/include-fixed"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.

So as I understand /usr/include is in search path, why make cannot find netipx/ipx.h?
Maybe the clue is in "make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.8.0-38-generic'", but there is no "usr/src/linux-headers-6.8.0-38-generic" in makefile. Where to look further?

You are trying to compile a kernel module. Kernel space programming rules are different. Most importantly, you can't just link in any random user-space library. The Makefile changes the search path so your code can only "see" kernel-appropriate includes.

@DevSolar, is the most appropriate action to complain to the developer in the repo on github as some search results showed for similar errors?

Possibly the module is trying to include a kernel header, but you are trying to force a standard library header on it instead.  Do you have the kernel headers for your kernel installed?

@JohnBollinger, I've just done as in https://www.tecmint.com/install-kernel-headers-in-ubuntu-and-debian/ : sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r) and got "linux-headers-6.8.0-38-generic is already the newest version (6.8.0-38.38)."

Ok.  Nevertheless, the header you are trying to get included is not suitable for use with a kernel module.  A kernel header is needed, and it seems overwhelmingly likely that that is what the module source intends to include (using the original name).  The header in /usr/include is simply irrelevant.

The project claims compatibility with Linux v4.7 and the last modification was 5 years ago.  It may simply be that it is not compatible with your v6.8 kernel.

Thanks to John's comment, I can say that net/ipx.h was removed in 5.15.0. What we have here is "code rot". That module won't compile with a modern kernel.

It appears you are using a cross-compiler to compile the kernel module, but it appears you are using the normal system compiler.  Can you run the same test on the compiler you are using to compile the kernel module and see where it looks for includes?

@DevSolar, John thank you. I've found more recent working driver code. Could you or John write a short answer so that I can accept a solution?

You can write an own answer and credit the ones that helped you.

Kernel uses the mode free-standing, so no standard library nor normal include path. Such libraries may not work on kernel (different expectation, and standard library may read files, which kernel cannot do it (with normal functions).

Commenters pointed out that I was trying to compile linux kernel module and project I was trying to compile is several years old and it not compatible with the kernel on my PC.
I've found more recent code for my hardware: https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu, it compiled and works. For me the problem is solved.

You can accept your own question. Glad we could help.
